# Purple screen at startup

Tags: boot

I was originally running Windows 7 Ultimate x64 on a Packard Bell. I decided to install Ubuntu 12.10 on my computer, used Wubi, and got to the screen where I could choose the OS. However, when I chose Ubuntu, a purple screen pops up. The hard drive DEL blinks, stops, and then the Caps Lock blinks. And then, nothing happens.

I try to use normal CD instead of Wubi and I was able to mount the iso on a USB drive using Universal USB Installer. I can get to the screen where I choose the boot order, select the USB drive, and then I get to a screen where Ubuntu seems to be 'loading' (purple with Ubuntu logo and name in the middle). Then, all of a sudden, I get a "Kernel Panic - Not syncing: fatal exception in interrupt" error message.

My specs : Intel Core 2 Duo CPU T5850 @ 2.16 GHz / 4 GB of ram / Packard Bell computer from 2007. / Windows 7 Ultimate x64 installed.

What should I do? I am not very good in computer sciences, I have tried CTRL+ALT+T, and ALT+F2, but nothing works.

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl+Alt+F1? It looks as if your disk is not being read.

Comment: I've tried pressing it at the purple screen. Nothing happens...

Comment: Please check if the answers to this question can help you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Answer (score 0):

Try using a bootable cd or usb, i tried wubi to install 12.04 lts on my pc for dual-boot with w7 x32 but ubuntu worked like hell, after installed from cd it worked as it should

Comment: Ok, I'll try that and get back to you all on whether or not it worked.
Thanks !

Comment: Hey, I was able to mount the iso on a USB drive using Universal USB Installer. I can get to the screen where I choose the boot order, select the USB drive, and then I get to a screen where Ubuntu seems to be 'loading' (purple with Ubuntu logo and name in the middle). Then, all of a sudden, I get a "Kernel Panic - Not syncing: fatal exception in interrupt" error message. 

My specs : Intel Core 2 Duo CPU T5850 @ 2.16 GHz /
4 GB of ram /
Packard Bell computer from 2007. /
Windows 7 Ultimate x64 installed.

    What should I do now ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you dint get to the part where you select "Try ubuntu or Install ubuntu", then the installer probably doesnt work(not installed properly on usb drive), make a bootable dvd(its the best method in my opinion,dont forget to write the dvd at minimum speed),if the same problem occurs then it might be a hardware issue.